# How to obtain orthogonal projections from `scipy.odr`?

Tags: python, scipy, fortran

I am fitting some orthogonal regression models with the methods/classes in `scipy.odr`.  After fitting, I would like to test my model on some out-of-training data by way of the residuals.  For ODR, the residuals take the form of a vector in the original space, for which I am interested in both the length and the direction.  The fitting procedure of the ODR must be able to compute these vectors, so such a method exists, but I am unable to find it.  Possibly it is implemented at a lower level and does not have hooks in the python API.

How do I obtain orthogonal projections from a point in the orginal space to the surface given by a `scipy.odr` fit?  Preferably in the python API, but if not, which methods exist in the FORTRAN 77 ODRPACK that I might hook into to perform this operation?

Comment: Use tag [tag:fortran] for all Fortran question.